# Warning: require(__DIR__/warp.php) - Switching Site from one server to another

Tags: php, wordpress, yoothemes

I am switching over a website that was built on Wordpress from one HostGator server to another HostGator server.  I have successfully transferred over the files via FTP, and migrated the MySQL database over and have both connected successfully.

I am running into an issue when I view the site in the browser and I receive this following error message:

Warning: require(**DIR**/warp.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abcworld/public_html/new2/wp-content/themes/yoo_moustache_wp1/index.php on line 10

Warning: require(**DIR**/warp.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/abcworld/public_html/new2/wp-content/themes/yoo_moustache_wp1/index.php on line 10

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**DIR**/warp.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php52/lib/php') in /home/abcworld/public_html/new2/wp-content/themes/yoo_moustache_wp1/index.php on line 10

When I switch to the themes that comes with Wordpress, the site is displayed with the data that is in the MySQL database, so it seems that the Template is what's causing the error.   I am using a Yootheme Template called 'Moustache' and have downloaded the latest version and uploaded it to Wordpress and the error message is still there.

The site I am working on is: http://abcworldwidestone.com/new2/

I am unsure what's causing this and would love some assistance - Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Updating the server to the latest version of PHP worked beautifully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server must still be using PHP 5.2 , use 5.3.3 or higher at least.

Answer (score 0):

As per [**the documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php);

> **5.3.0** Added **DIR** and **NAMESPACE** constants

You are more than likely running PHP version < 5.3.0.